# Execute bat file using node js

Tags: node.js, batch-file, child-process

I have written code to execute bat file using nodejs, but it is restricting me to place the bat file at the same location where package.json file is present and it is not accepting absolute path.
I am using the following code:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','coma.bat']);

    bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log('data is : '+data.toString());
    });

    bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error('error is : '+data.toString());
    });

    bat.on('exit', (code) => {
      console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

it accepts full path (if this is the question):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c','C:\\scripts\\somescript.bat']);
```

Comment: @RohanBatra - I've tried it too and it is working. What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @RohanBatra does the path contains spaces or other special symbols?